# Associate scraped data to the right item

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I suppose to this item class for the scrapy framework:

```
class PersonItem(scrapy.Item):
 name = scrapy.Field()
 address = scrapy.Field()
 phone = scrapy.Field()
```

I suppose to scrap an html page where not everyone has got a phone number and I obtain 3 different lists: the first 2 are with all the data that I need and the third one with less elements than the other 2 lists.

example:

```
 list 1=[name1, name2, name3]
 list 2=[addr1, addr2, addr3]
 list 3=[phone1, phone3]
```

Which is the best way to associate the phone number to the right person?

Comment: can you scrape the page so that people without phone numbers have `None` as their number, or something similar?

Comment: It depend on the web page structure. Of course if a field is empty is possible to retrieve a null data but in most of the cases, if the field is empty, the field is omitted  at all. I used the "and" operator in xpath, retrieving the useful data + other data(in the example i retrieve something like name+phone) and then, working on the string, I select the only data that i need. Maybe there is a more elegant way to do that...

Comment: Could you provide samples of the three lists you're getting.  I'm not quite clear on how your data is formatted.

Comment: I 've edited the question

Comment: yeah the way to match them up is to put `None` (or some other spacer value) in the list where there is no phone number.  Then you just use `zip` to get tuples like `(name1, addr1, phone1)` and process those.

Comment: How do you know who has no phone-number? I need to deduce the right element's position from the page, because if i process 100 web pages I cannot manually insert "none" in the right position for each list...

Comment: You have to modify the rules you are using to scrape the webpage.  There's no way to recover that information once the data is stored in the lists